# How to read a postmessage sent to a parent element using WKScriptMessageHandler?

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview

I'm loading an URL in WKWebView that is sending a postmessage to a parent element:

```
window.parent.test.postMessage('A message')
```

I'm implementing WKScriptMessageHandler and trying to get that message using userController(didReceiveMessage):

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if(message.name == "test") {
        print("JavaScript is sending a message \(message.body)")

    }
}
```

the message.body is somethink like

```
{
   command = "015.1";
}
```

I want to read this value 015.1 to a string variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the message should be passed as a dictionary

```
window.parent.test.postMessage({"command":id})

func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print("chegou mensagem do javascript ")
        print(message.body)
        print(message.name)
        let dict = message.body as? NSDictionary;
        let str = dict?["command"] as? String
        print(str ?? "")
```